# Does surface area of a torus depends on its center

Tags: calculus, area

I need to solve the following problem:

Let S be a torus parallel to the xy plane, centered at (2,3,3), with major radius 6 and minor radius 5. Calculate the surface area of S, using appropriate integral.

Knowing that the surface area formula, that is obtained using parametrization, is $4\pi^2ab$, is my area just $120\pi^2$? Why do we need center?

Comment: You don't really need it if you just want to know the surface

Comment: You're told to set up an appropriate integral.  Using the formula would not be consistent with that directive.  While you do not need to know the coordinates of the center, it plays a role in how the resulting integral will be written.

Comment: @heropup Can you give me an idea how the integral should look like, since the parametrization formula I know, I mean integral from which  $4\pi^2ab$ is derived doesn't include coordinates of the center?

Comment: The sensible thing to do is to set up the integral using a convenient coordinate system in which the torus is centred at $(0,0,0)$ instead of $(2,3,3)$.  Actually, cylindrical coordinates would be even better.